# Extracting date and time from .wav filenames in r

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a column of site_date_time.wav files which I need to parse the date and time segments of. Each file name is named like this: AF10_20160602_183000.wav.

I've used `gsub(".wav", "", filename)` to remove the .wav, and I've used `as.Date(sub('[^_]+_(\\d+).*', '\\1', df[,5]), "%Y%m%d")` to extract the date, but I can't seem to make this method work for the time segment.

I tried using  `sub('^[^_]+_[^_]+_(\\d{2})(\\d{2})_.*', '\\1:\\2', df[,5])` for the time to make it into a separate value to then use strptime, but it wouldn't work. I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.

If I could put date and time together into a single column that would be even better. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Can you share some sample data that possibly includes some variation (15-20) records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove everything until first underscore with `sub` and then use `as.POSIXct` to convert to date-time value.

```
x <- c('AF10_20160602_183000.wav', 'BF10_20160602_143000.wav')
as.POSIXct(sub('.*?_', '', x), format = '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.wav', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2016-06-02 18:30:00 UTC" "2016-06-02 14:30:00 UTC"
```

You can also use `lubridate::ymd_hms` :

```
lubridate::ymd_hms(sub('.*?_', '', x))
```